# Does migrating a site that is 99% several megs of static HTML from Apache to Google App Enging make sense?

Tags: apache, google-app-engine, web-hosting, cloud

I have a large site of mostly static content, and I have entertained migrating to Google App Engine. I am wondering, not so much if it is possible as whether that is cutting a steak with a screwdriver. I see a way to do it in Django that has a bad design smell.

Does migrating a literature site that is largely static HTML from Apache to Google App Engine make sense? I'm not specifically asking for a comparison to Nginx or Cherokee; I am interested in whether migrating from a traditional web
hosting solution to a more cloudy type of solution recommends itself.

The site is JonathansCorner.com, and is presently unavailable ("the magic blue smoke has escaped").

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that's a perfectly legitimate use of App Engine. Simply upload your content with an app.yaml (or appengine-web.xml, depending on your preferred flavor) that serves some or all of the site as static.